# Code Not Deleting Tables

Tags: c#, dao

I am using very similar syntax to delete Query's but when I try to check if a table exists and delete it the table is not actually deleted.  Did I miss a step or use incorrect syntax?

```
string path = "C:\\Database\\EmployeeInfo\\EmpInfo.mdb";
bool found = false;
DAO.DBEngine db = new DAO.DBEngine();
dd = db.OpenDatabase(path);
try
{
  string[] tableNames = new string[3]
  {
    supName + "_Profile1",
    supName + "_Profile2",
    supName + "_Profile3",
  };
  for (int q = tableNames.GetLowerBound(0); q <= tableNames.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
  {
    foreach (DAO.TableDef tabledef in dd.TableDefs)
    {
      string newName = Convert.ToString(q);
      if (tabledef.Name == newName)
      {  
        found = true;
      }
      if (found)
      {
        dd.TableDefs.Delete(newName);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT --- Simple Syntax mistake....the code should have been:

```
string newName = tableNames[q];
```

Comment: You probably cannot modify `dd.TableDefs` while iterating over `dd.TableDefs`

Comment: Grrr...Any suggestion on a workaround so I can check multiple table names?

Comment: @Vkt0rS. Deleting the curly braces like you did here did not "improve" anything. Using curly braces with all control statements, even if they have one line, is a perfectly legitimate (and in my opinion, beneficial) practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you meant to build up the new name? Currently you have

> string newName = Convert.ToString(q);

so newName is only ever a number. Unlikely to match your table names.

Comment: AH -- such a simple coding error.  If I update it to string newName = tableNames[1]; it will do exactly as desired!